# Count the distinct words

Tags: bash, awk

I have an input file is like:

```
com.a.b
com.c.d
com.a.b
com.e.f
com.e.f
com.e.f
```

And I would like the output to be like:

```
com.a.b 2
com.c.d 1
com.e.f 3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't mind a slight variation in the given output then the traditional approach is  with `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
      2 com.a.b
      1 com.c.d
      3 com.e.f
```

Otherwise use a scripting language that has associative arrays such as `awk`:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file
com.e.f 3
com.c.d 1
com.a.b 2
```

Pipe to `sort` for ordering:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k]}' file | sort
com.a.b 2
com.c.d 1
com.e.f 3
```

Comment: `sort file | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'` also provides the correct output.

Comment: @Swiss given the example input that would also be a good solution but it's not a great general solution as the number of fields per line need to be fixed.